# Set layout to viewport height, at a minimum

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid to create header / content / footer areas.

The issue I have is that:

- I can either set up the grid to use all viewport space by giving it a height. But then if my content is larger than the viewport My footer overlaps it.
- Or not give it a height, and in this case the footer stays at the bottom of the content, but if content is small my grid will not take all the viewport.

Is there a way to have both? Ideally in case content is small I want the grid to take all the viewport, but in case it is larger then simply use the needed space.

I have a codepen that illustrates the problem : https://codepen.io/jlengrand/pen/Krbaob

```css
.app {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}

content {
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Main content</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try min-height, instead of height?

Comment: Well, I didn't know that was a thing. Seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min-height` instead of `height` or, since you're using Grid, use the `minmax` function:

```css
.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh minmax(80vh, auto) 10vh;
}

header {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app>* {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<article class="app">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br>Main content<br></p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </footer>
</article>
```

### [revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmRmwP)

Comment: Hey there. You example is what I have now indeed. But it creates a sticky footer essentially. This is something that I do not desire :). I would like to have the footer simply stay at the end of the content, but always at least fill an entire page.

Comment: Okay. Answer revised. If you have any more questions let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to revise. And enjoy Christmas :)